# Android Annotation injection in PagerAdapter and all of subclasses

Tags: dependency-injection, annotations, ebean, android-annotations

I implementing "Android Annotation" in my project. I want to inject references in to **FragmentPagerAdapter** class with @EBean, But @EBean need only one constructor with max one parameter of type context.

but as you know PagerAdapter and its sub-classes has constructor with FragmentManager parameter as input.
when build, this error appear:

```
Error:(23, 1) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean annotated element should have a constructor with one parameter max, of type android.content.Context
```

how to inject in this class?
(I need injection because I use async and bean annotations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to mark `FragmentPagerAdapter` with `@EBean`, because of the `super` constructor.

Comment: thanks for answer, may I ask u to propose alternative solution/lib/hack for it?

Comment: The only workaround i see is wrapping the `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a `@EBean`, where you can inject anything, then set the `FragmentPagerAdapter` object to it manually. But it will be rather ugly because you have to use callbacks.